# Looping through 100 text files in Python

Tags: python, pandas, log-analysis

My python code is as below:

```
#Loading libraries
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

#Creating an empty dataframe
columns = ['A']
df_ = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
df_ = df_.fillna(0)

#Reading the data line by line
with open('serverLogs.log-2020-04-30-01') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    #print(lines)
    for line in lines:
        parts  = line.split('OD_MAKER_DATE=') 
        df_ = df_.append(parts)
```

I have many text files whereby the last two digits on the text file name change and they range from 01 to 100 i.e 'serverLogs.log-2020-04-30-**01**', 'serverLogs.log-2020-04-30-**02**'...'serverLogs.log-2020-04-30-**100**'.

How can i create a for loop at the beginning of my existing code to loop through the 100 files and append the individual lines in the dataframe df_ instead of loading one file at a time? I am not very familiar with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way overall to read the files in loop. But what I could understand is that for the first 9 files, you would need a 0 appended. This code might solve your problem of generating the required names:

```
file_count = 100 # can change it to any value
base_name = 'serverLogs.log-2020-04-30-{}'

for i in range(file_count):
    file_name = base_name.format("%.2d" % (i+1))
```

Then, you can read the data from the files in loop and append the same way as you are doing right now:

```
#Reading the data line by line
with open(file_name) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        parts  = line.split('OD_MAKER_DATE=') 
        df_ = df_.append(parts)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for idx in range(101):
  fname = ("serverLogs.log-2020-04-30-%d" % idx)
  with open(fname) as f:
    ...
```

Comment: Hi curlycharcoal, your code is working fine for file number 10 to 100, however, for files number 1 to 9, am getting an error of file not found because of the missing leading zeros i.e. 01,02...09. How can i incorporate the missing zeros?

Comment: @RianeRoseKinuthia instead of %d, use %02d

Comment: Cool. However, the first file this prints will have a suffix 00. Can be changed to the following code: for idx in range(100):
  fname = ("serverLogs.log-2020-04-30-%02d" % (idx+1))

Comment: @Anshul Jain, now the code is running  after i made that change. No errors generated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use string formating and loop through the numbers 1-100 to read all the 100 files

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime


columns = ['A']
df_ = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
df_ = df_.fillna(0)

for i in range(101):
    with open('serverLogs.log-2020-04-30-{}'.format("%.2d" % i)) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        #print(lines)


for line in lines:
        parts  = line.split('OD_MAKER_DATE=') 
        df_ = df_.append(parts)
```

Comment: When i tried this, i got an error since with your code, the files start at 00 instead of 01. I made a minor change in the for loop to have `for i in range(1,101)' on order to eliminate the error.

Comment: this can be used directly without handling the case of 1-9 separately as you need 01,02,03 ........

Answer (score 0):

```
#Loading libraries
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

#Creating an empty dataframe
columns = ['A']
df_ = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
df_ = df_.fillna(0)

#Reading the data line by line
file_name = 'serverLogs.log-2020-04-30-{}'
for i in range(101):
    file_name = file_name.format("%.2d" % (i+1))
    with open(file_name) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        #print(lines)
        for line in lines:
            parts  = line.split('OD_MAKER_DATE=')
            df_ = df_.append(parts)
```

Comment: Am getting an error. The files start at 00 instead of 01.